# Arched upper arrow symbol?

Tags: symbols, arrows

The symbol in between $\neq$ and $\epsilon$ in the picture below is an arched arrow to the right. How can one produce this symbol and its left-oriented counterpart?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `amssymb` package has `\curvearrowright` (and `curvearrowleft`) which can be used in a superscript.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$\ne,{}^{\curvearrowright},\varepsilon$

\end{document}
```

Comment: That does it! Thanks.

Comment: @lafinur: It may seem strange, but on this site we typically [don't use comments for giving thanks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Instead, we show appreciation by [upvoting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) all helpful answers. Also, it is sometimes a good idea to wait a day or two before accepting an answer to see if there are other solutions that might be better. (Once you accept an answer you typically don't get many new responses.)

Comment: Good to know, I come from Math Stack Exchange, where this is usual behavior. Thanks for letting me know.